# Why is it possible to vote for deletion/undeletion more than once?

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete, voting-limits

If you vote to close a question and it later gets reopened, you are not allowed to vote to close it again.

If you vote to reopen a question and it later gets closed again, you are not allowed to vote to reopen it again.

But if you vote to delete a question and it later gets undeleted, you *are* allowed to vote to delete it again, and (I assume) the same goes for undeleting. Why the inconsistency?

I can think of two possible reasons:

1. When the no-close-twice rule was implemented, it was to solve the problem of open-close wars. There have not to my knowledge been delete-undelete wars, so it was deemed unnecessary to impose the same rules on deleting/undeleting.
2. When the no-close-twice rule was implemented, they simply forgot to apply it to delete/undelete votes as well.

Is one of these correct, or is there another reason?

Note that this *has* resulted in delete/undelete conflicts, even between moderators and users:

[image: Screenshot of the post history]

Comment: Huh... I'm not sure i've ever even *tried* voting to delete a question that i'd previously voted to delete. *goes off to scan "recently undeleted" list...*

Comment: Can we have a link to the question that the screenshot is referencing? I cant seem to remember that one just from the deletion names.

Comment: I agree with Behaviour--there's a need for this to be revisited in some sites.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I forget why we didn't apply it :)

Seriously though, we haven't seen widespread delete/undelete wars.  Before adding additional rules/complexity, we like to see how the community uses a feature.

If it ain't broke, don't fix it!

#### Status as of April 10, 2013:

There have only been 111 questions on Stack Overflow where someone's cast more than one delete vote.

This includes questions where a delete vote was cleared by re-opening and then later re-applied after re-closing, but excludes situations where folks deleted/undeleted/redeleted their own questions and those where moderators did the same.

Many of the questions involved are extremely long-lived poll questions that were controversial well before we even started tracking this stuff, so the actual numbers might be *slightly* higher; still, there does not appear to be any broad pattern of abuse.

#### Why *hasn't* this been abused?

Well, closing and deletion aren't really separate systems - deletion *requires* closing, and because of this there really isn't much opportunity for it to be abused. A close-reopen war can occur on any question, but for a delete-undelete battle to occur, you need:

- A post with enough supporters to undelete it after it's been deleted once, but...
- ...Without enough support to be *re-opened*, and...
- ...Without enough controversy to get moderators involved (as their delete votes are binding and they can lock a post to prevent it from being deleted).

Undeletion is pretty rare, but over half of all questions that do get undeleted by vote are then re-opened, invalidating any pending delete-votes and preventing any new ones. Because delete-voting *requires* that a question be closed first, you'd need a fresh set of close-voters to even have a chance at casting a second delete vote on a re-opened question.

Comment: Well, I only mentioned it because I saw it here: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3947/list. That's the "music to listen to while coding" question that I asked about a couple of days ago.

Comment: I don't mean to say that it's a delete war yet, just that it's been deleted twice by a total of four people.

Comment: Fortunately, that one stayed deleted the second time around (sorry, mmyers). No war, just emphatic action...

Comment: I think this could use a revisit

Comment: I just raised [another MSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176024/158605) about this. Do you think this should be re-evaluated? Personally I think it's "broke" :)

Comment: @Rachel I've brought it to the attention of the community team - it's not a difficult change, so I have no objections there.

Comment: @Rachel: See my update to this answer.

Comment: @Shog9 per my reading of your update, basically plan is to wait until there's [more evidence](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169551/165773 "with active deletion campains at MSO this might happen faster that one would think") of abuse? like it was with [sticky hot questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99077/165773 "'hundred year floods' yeah sure")... oh wait we probably won't give a damn even then. Heh, decline culture at SE is [not in the best shape](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8843182#8843182 "rant here")

Comment: No, the plan is to wait for evidence that this even *can* be abused. Close-warring was an actual, visible problem at one point, but the mechanics for how delete works are already considerably different and in four years there's not been any indication that *this part* of their design isn't working just fine. Also... You're really stuck on that hot question thing, @gnat - and that hasn't been declined, it just doesn't have the priority you think it does.

Comment: @Shog9 well to me the [case recently presented by Rachel](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176024/165773) looks like abuse. I mean, repeated un/deletions by biased meta participants on the question being actively discussed at meta and having edits and reopen votes pending smell quite fishy...

Comment: ...(As for the hot questions, I am merely making sure that I paid my civic duties by giving it proper meta exposure prior to proceeding with [guerilla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170419/should-trending-questions-be-auto-protected#comment511558_170419). Y'know, this buggy algorithm turned out pretty easy to manipulate - I don't feel like stuck)

Comment: @gnat: deleting questions that are under heavy meta discussion is kind of a separate issue; even so, that particular question had enough moderator involvement before it was even deleted *once* to make it a poor example of anything (beyond, perhaps, the need for moderators to be more proactive when they identify a controversial question) - for various reasons, I don't think it's feasible to ever limit moderator votes in this manner.

Comment: @Shog9 just to avoid confusion, question doesn't read like being about limiting diamonds deletions (there are no mod-related tags). Per my reading it's about 10Kers (probably worth tagging [meta-tag:10K-tools] for clarity on that)

Comment: @gnat: I know - that's why I excluded moderators (current and past) from my data. However, there's a ton of moderator involvement in Rachel's example, which I tend to think invalidates it to a degree - in a certain sense, *most* moderator-votes are multi-votes.

Comment: @Shog9 regarding Rachel's example, [its screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8ervo.png) clearly shows no diamonds within freehand circles

Comment: @gnat: there's a diamond on the undelete line... And that's *after* it'd been closed, twice, by two different moderators. Also not shown: two subsequent undeletions and a re-deletion by a moderator. I think they have it under control. (should I invite you to chat since we're already in chat?)

Comment: @Shog9 To be fair, the first undelete/delete by George was solely to mod-delete the question and prevent it from getting undeleted. The 2nd undelete was to lock the question instead of deleting it after I [raised some objections](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175507#comment528149_175688) to that. I'm OK with "we don't see any pattern of abuse so far so this isn't a priority for us", but I'd like to be sure it's checked on every once in a while. I think if this was widely known, it may get abused a lot more by small groups of users, and moderators would have to keep stepping in :)

Comment: @Rachel: it's easy enough to check, but right now... Undeletion itself is rare; undeletion without re-opening rarer still - there's just not that much *opportunity* for abuse here.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm more concerned about repeated deletes than undeletes, especially since undeletes are harder to get attention for and there's no mod-undelete the way there is a mod-delete to stop them. I've had users tell me they vote to delete solely because there's a reopen attempt for the post and they don't think it should be reopened, and often feel delete votes get incorrectly used in place of editing or explaining the problem. I hate seeing a user coming to meta asking why their question was closed and for help editing/reopening it, only to see the post get deleted instead.

Comment: @Shog9 Out of curiosity, when you said your query excluded posts where a moderator was involved in the delete/undelete, do you mean all delete/undelete votes for that post were not evaluated? Or just the moderator votes were not evaluated in the result set?

Comment: Just the moderator votes, @Rachel.

Comment: @Shog9 Ok thanks, that's a surprisingly low number :)

Comment: @Rachel: there are scarcely more questions that've been undeleted but not re-opened. I've edited this answer again to try and elaborate a bit on *why* I don't believe this is (or will be) a problem.

Comment: @Shog9: on mathematics,SE at least, this does seem to be an issue - although I don't have a query at hand to count the number of multi-votes. I had posted another question about this on meta.SE, which unfortunately didn't get much attention: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250433/revisiting-user-can-vote-to-delete-more-than-once?noredirect=1#comment817512_250433

Comment: I completely agree with Carl's comment (almost 3 years ago), I am also coming from MSE.There are some situation that even the mod cannot conclude the delete/undelete war, until some users will ask a new (more or less identical) questions, then the war ends because it can be closed only once.

Comment: In MSE some users forms a chatroom discussing closure/deletion. If they really want to delete a question, there's no way you can stop them. This is at the very least not align with the idea that the site is moderated by the communities, instead of a group of several users.

Comment: If there is no drawback and changing it is easy, please do change it.

Comment: @Shog9 This may not have been a problem as of 2013, but does the data show it's a problem today? I do think it's a problem on [scifi.se] at least, where [quite](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/114500/revisions) a [few](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/181283/revisions) questions have had enough deletions and undeletions - involving mostly the same users - that the mods have had to lock them just to stop the yoyoing. (I'd like to make a new main meta question about this, but I'm sure it'd just get dupehammered back to this one.)

Comment: That's sorta why HL exists, @Rand. But feel free to post a question on SciFi meta.

Comment: This answer has been wrong/out of date at *least* since it was posted, probably before then, too. It *is* broken; please fix it.

Comment: FYI, [this is now changing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371277/335251).