# Same user can delete/undelete a post more than once

Tags: support, bug, vote-to-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why is it possible to vote for deletion/undeletion more than once?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/why-is-it-possible-to-vote-for-deletion-undeletion-more-than-once)

Is it supposed to be possible for the same user to vote to delete/undelete a post [more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11565350/revisions)?

[image: Screenshot of the post history]

Close/reopen votes don't allow this, so I'm not sure why delete/undelete votes would, unless it's a bug

Comment: I was kind of surprised too, when it accepted the delete vote. However, the internet is IMO better off with that answer deleted, so I didn't mind.

Comment: And though I think it is a duplicate, the answer isn't that satisfactory to be honest.

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo I don't think it's a dupe because the answer was "if it ain't broke" ...well, it's broke. So fix it.

Comment: @BenBrocka I mean, the question is still definitely a dupe.  The unsatisfying answer doesn't make it not a dupe, but it may make it worth revisiting :)

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo it's already been marked. I'm not sure it's as practical to try and resuscitate a 3 year old post

Comment: One difference is that there are about 18000 people with the possibility to get involved in an open/close war, but only 3000 users have the option to delete/undelete (and with a much lower number of votes per person). Perhaps that makes it a non-problem in practice?